# Поиск CSS селектора

Tags: css, css-selectors

Найти css селектор на  http://suninjuly.github.io/cats.html который возвращает изображение второго кота (serious cat)

Я пробовал сделать   `div.col-sm-4 >div:nth-child(1)  [src="images/serious_cat.jpg"]` 
И оно как бы находит, всё хорошо, но ответ не принимается из-за наличия квадратных скобок ответ не засчитывается

Если есть другие варианты решения, покажите их пожалуйста

Comment: А если кавычки поменять на простые? `'`

Comment: А если убрать проблеы перед квадратными скобками?

Comment: Не помогает замена кавычек, скорее всего нужен принципеально другой ответ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не вижу больше вариантов.

```css
.col-sm-4:nth-child(2) img
```

Answer (score 0):

`.row :nth-child(2) img`

Так-же вот

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]